# Optimize FB Social Plugin Performance

Tags: facebook

I am reading this article about Optimize Social Plugin Performance

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

The article describes how to use `channelUrl` with `channel.html` file.

The thing is that the article is about XFBML Social Plugins, wheras I am using HTML5 Social Plugins.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

My question is how to and/or do I still need to use the `channelUrl` with `channel.html` with HTML5 Social Plugins? 
I can't find any info that talks about `channelUrl` in context of HTML5 Social Plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you are embedding the plugins via XFBML or HTML5 tags does not make a lot of difference. They both get parsed by the JS SDK, and that is what’s making some cross domain requests in the background, and the channel.html file is a means of speeding those up <del>in older browsers</del>.

So, to clearly answer your question: **Yes**, you should give an address for your channel.html file, no matter whether you are using XFBML *or* HTML5 tags to embed social plugins.

Comment: Two questions:1) You sad old browsers, but the doc I read doesn't say anything about old browsers. The doc says that channel.html will prevent recreating a copy of a page in the background. Am I missing something?
2) How do I modify HTML5 code in OP to incorporate the channelUrl? I did not find any code examples on how to do this in HTML5. Thx!

Comment: 1) Strike that – I guess I read it somewhere, but from their blog entry it seems to be relevant for current browsers as well. 2) It’s right there on the blog page you mentioned, and on the start page of the JS SDK docs it’s described as well, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/